# Adding min qty on running total per day

Tags: sql, min

I have a query that gives the running total of stock less sales on a daily basis and need to show the min available quantity to ensure that sales do not oversell.
In Excel I can run min on a range, what is the equivalent for SQL?
[image: Excel Image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want the quantity sold over time (Sales column in the table below) and ensure that it doesn't exceed the available_to_sell amount?

Reference code:

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(daily_total) OVER (PARTITION BY stockcode ORDER BY date) AS aa,
    LAG(Available_To_Sell) OVER (PARTITION BY stockcode ORDER BY date) AS a_t_s_lag
  FROM
    `optimal-weft-418017.78207210.78207210_01`
  ORDER BY
    stockcode,
    date
  LIMIT
    100),
  b AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN aa-daily_total < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE
    aa-daily_total
  END
    AS Sales
  FROM
    a
  ORDER BY
    stockcode,
    date)
SELECT
  *EXCEPT(a_t_s_lag,
    aa),
  CASE
    WHEN Sales>a_t_s_lag THEN 'Exceeds Available Qty'
    WHEN Sales IS NULL THEN NULL
  ELSE
  'OK'
END
  AS QA
FROM
  b
ORDER BY
  stockcode,
  date
```

Output Table:

| StockCode | Date | Daily_Total | Available_To_Sell | Sales | QA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 3A | 2020-01-01 | 23 | 6 | *null* | *null* |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-19 | 22 | 6 | 1 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-20 | 20 | 6 | 2 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-21 | 15 | 6 | 5 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-25 | 10 | 6 | 5 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-26 | 6 | 6 | 4 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-03-28 | 8 | 6 | 0 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-04 | 7 | 6 | 1 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-08 | 7 | 6 | 0 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-09 | 6 | 6 | 1 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-10 | 11 | 11 | 0 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-15 | 11 | 11 | 0 | OK |
| Item 3A | 2024-04-22 | 11 | 11 | 0 | OK |
| Item 4A | 2020-01-01 | 4 | 4 | *null* | *null* |
| Item 4A | 2024-03-20 | 3 | 3 | 1 | OK |
| Item 4A | 2024-03-25 | 1 | 1 | 2 | OK |
| Item 4A | 2024-03-26 | 1 | 1 | 0 | OK |

Comment: After originally accepting the answer I have now realised that there was confusion to my request.

Comment: What I need is a way of giving the values Available_To_Sell column. I currently only have StockCode, Date and Daily_Total columns.